# How to download file in the directory created

Tags: java, android

I have already created a directory or a path in my android device using:

```
File dlFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/RAS/download/files");
```

And I downloaded a file from my server:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://IPADDRESS/RAS/phpword/outputs/template.docx");
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
```

How do I put my downloaded file to the directory or path that I have created?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Data")
            .setDescription("Downloading")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/RAS/download/files", "test.docx");

    mgr.enqueue(request);
```

This is the line where you provide the path

```
setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/RAS/download/files", "test.docx");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to make sure you have the following permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And most importantly, if your **target API 23** and the app is running on an **Android 6.0+** device, you have to add [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**.

```
private static final int REQUEST = 111;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
    } else {
        downloadFile();
    }
} else {
     downloadFile();
}
```

Get permission result like this.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    downloadFile();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write in your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can try like below.

```
private void downloadFile(){
   Uri uri= Uri.parse("http://IPADDRESS/RAS/phpword/outputs/template.docx");

   // Create request for android download manager
   DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
   DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri); 
   request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

   // set title and description
   request.setTitle("Downloading");
   request.setDescription("File download using DownloadManager.");

   request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

   request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

   //set the local destination for download file to a path within the application's external files directory
   request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"template.docx"); // here file will be download in download directory as template.docs, you can change the directory and file name as you want.
   request.setMimeType("*/*");
   downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```